# There doesn't appear to be support for UITabBar in SwiftUI. Workarounds?

Tags: uitabbar, swiftui

SwiftUI doesn't appear to support UITabBar. How can I integrate that capability?

Merely wrapping the view like one would a (eg) MKMapView, doesn't work because of its need for deep integration with NavigationView. Using UINavigationView is too un-SwiftUI-ish.

Comment: I'm assuming you understand how to integrate `UIKit classes with `SwiftUI` view structs. If not, then watch WWDC session 231 about it. If you do know what I'm talking about, then also understand that it's barely in beta 2. You may get lucky and a `TabBar()` may be coming by GM.

Comment: Actually SwiftUI have 'TabbedView' which behave almost the same. It doesn't support all UITabbar features for now, but will probably before final release in sep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'TabbedView' is the closest thing. It can be used similar to the following:

```swift
    struct TabView : View {

        @State private var selection = 1

        var body: some View {
            TabbedView (selection: $selection) {
                InboxList()
                    .tabItemLabel(selection == 1 ? Image("second") : Image("first"))
                    .tag(1)

                PostsList()
                    .tabItemLabel(Image("first"))
                    .tag(2)

                Spacer()
                    .tabItemLabel(Image("first"))
                    .tag(3)

                Spacer()
                    .tabItemLabel(Image("second"))
                    .tag(4)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for my question. Unfortunately I mis-stated the question as I was seeking a ToolBar not a TabBar. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't happy with `TabbedView`, you can always roll your own! Here's a quick base implementation:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {

    let tabs = [TabItemView(title: "Home", content: { Text("Home page text") }), TabItemView(title: "Other", content: { Text("Other page text") }), TabItemView(title: "Pictures", content: { Text("Pictures page text") })]

    var body: some View {
        TabBar(tabs: tabs, selectedTab: tabs[0])
    }
}

struct TabItemView<Content> : Identifiable where Content : View {
    var id = UUID()
    var title: String
    var content: Content

    init(title: String, content: () -> Content) {
        self.title = title
        self.content = content()
    }


    var body: _View { content }

    typealias Body = Never
}

struct TabBar<Content>: View where Content : View {
    let tabButtonHeight: Length = 60

    var tabs: [TabItemView<Content>]
    @State var selectedTab: TabItemView<Content>

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            self.selectedTab.content.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height - self.tabButtonHeight)

            Divider()
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(self.tabs) { tab in
                        Button(action: { self.selectedTab = tab}) {
                            Text(tab.title)
                        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(Double(self.tabs.count)), height: self.tabButtonHeight)

                    }
                }
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.4))
            }
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this but isn't this essentially just a TabbedView? I don't need/want the content to change. But, you have given me the essence of a roll-your own TabBar... only issue is that UITabBar has some special behaviors wrt the UINavigationView that it lives in / coordinates with.

Comment: And by TabBar, I meant ToolBar... hence the answers I got. Sorry!

Comment: Best answer ever ! There is so much to do with swiftui but I need so much more documentations

Answer (score 0):

UITabBar seems to be working now on Xcode 13.3, SwiftUI 3, iOS15+
It works even though I didn't import UIKit, not sure if that has any effect but it's working for me

```
    struct LandingView: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: String
    
    //hiding tab bar
    init(selectedTab: Binding<String>) {
        self._selectedTab = selectedTab
        UITabBar.appearance().isHidden = true 
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        //Tab view with tabs
        TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
            //Views
            Home() 
                .tag("Home")
            PlaylistView()
                .tag("My Playlists")
            HistoryView()
                .tag("History")
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I misstated the question as I was trying to make ToolBar... below is the code I ended up with... thanks to all.

```
struct ToolBarItem : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String
    var imageName : String
    var action: () -> Void
}

struct TooledView<Content> : View where Content : View{
    var content :  Content
    var items : [ToolBarItem]
    let divider = Color.black.opacity(0.2)

    init(items : [ToolBarItem], content: () -> Content){
        self.items = items
        self.content = content()
    }
    var body : some View{
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            self.content
            self.divider.frame(height: 1)
            ToolBar(items: self.items).frame(height: ToolBar.Height)
        }
    }
}

struct ToolBar : View{
    static let Height : Length = 60
    var items : [ToolBarItem]
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(spacing: 0){
                ForEach(self.items){ item in
                    Button(action: item.action){
                        Image(systemName: item.imageName).imageScale(.large)
                        Text(item.title).font(.caption)
                    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(Double(self.items.count)))

                }

            }
                .frame(height: ToolBar.Height)
                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.10))
        }
    }
}
```